# Как спроектировать привязку бизнес-процесса к пользователю должным образом?

Tags: ооп, архитектура

Допустим...

Есть некая программа, которая обрабатывает некоторые сообщения, формирует документы, раскладывает их в какие-то архивы, что-то из этого записывает в базу данных, что-то читает от туда, в общем, осуществляет некую подобную деятельность. С этой программой работают разные пользователи, т.е. получается, что разные сообщения принадлежат разным пользователям, от сюда и документы, архивы и все прочее тоже рассматривается с привязкой к какому-то пользователю (причём, если это имеет значение, пользовательские процессы не пересекаются, всё это один бизнес-процесс, который выполняется параллельно независимо для каждого пользователя).

Так вот... Как подобную привязку бизнес-процесса к пользователю должным образом спроектировать? Ведь получается, что всё: создание и обработка сообщений, каких-то документов, архивов, даже, например, логирование процесса, необходимо вести с указанием пользователя, привязкой к нему. Получается, что при создании сообщения в конструктор необходимо передать не только источник сообщения, но и пользователя, что бы объект-сообщение связать с пользователем, а затем в процессе, когда, например, на основе этого сообщения возникает ещё какая-то сущность, то там тоже надо в конструкторе передать + и информацию о пользователе, что бы была привязка, что бы понимать какой именно пользователь сейчас с этим работает, что бы, опять же, логировать с указанием информации о пользователе лога. И так всё и вся...

Мне кажется, что я что-то не понимаю, неужели всё так? Или есть какие-то другие решения данного вопроса...

Comment: Пока все довольно абстрактно. Все пользователи работают с одним экземпляром программы (процессом, деревом процессов) или у каждого свой экземпляр?

Comment: @avp Все работают с одним экземпляром. Программа работает на сервере, пользователи отправляют данные, программа их обрабатывает и имеет некий результат.

Comment: Наверное в процедуре логина нужно создавать структуру данных, в которой будет id пользователя. Далее в этой структуре (объекте) вы можете хранить все необходимые для текущего состояния сеанса данные. Просто передаете ее  во все процедуры, которые меняют ее содержимое в ходе работы.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть за формирование документа отвечает один компонент, за хранение - другой компонент, за работу с пользователями - третий (а может быть несколько: Авторизация, определение прав, хранение и тд) компонент.

Компоненту формирования документов не надо знать о пользователях, ему, к примеру, надо будет дополнительно передать ФИО.

Компоненту хранения надо будет знать id пользователя - просто передайте его ему.

Этим компонентам не важна сущность пользователя, для них ФИО или тот же id это просто входящие наважно откуда данные, такие же как Название документа или что-то подобное.

За бизнес-процесс отвечает тоже какой-нибудь контроллер.

Таким образом компоненты работают отдельно и независимо, для них имеют значение только входные данные и конфиг.